# Show that modified energy-momentum tensor defines conserved currents

Tags: electromagnetism, conservation-laws, field-theory, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In [David Tong's notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html) on quantum field theory, one of the problems asks to show that a tensor defined by

$$\Theta^{\mu\nu}=T^{\mu\nu}-F^{\rho\mu}\partial_\rho A^\nu$$

where $F^{\rho\mu}=\partial^\rho A^\mu - \partial^\mu A^\rho$ for the electromagnetic four-potential $A$, and $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor defined from the Lagrangian. The problem is to show that this defines four conserved currents.

Presumably I should just show that $\partial_\mu\Theta^{\mu\nu}=0$, and thus each of the four values of $\nu$ gives a conserved current. By definition $\partial_\mu T^\mu_\nu=0$, and since this is in Minkowski space, this should mean that $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$. So the problem amounts to showing that
$$ \partial_\mu(F^{\rho\mu}\partial_\rho A^\nu)=0.$$

But as far as I can tell, this is just not true. For one thing, it contains only one term of $(\partial_\mu\partial^\mu A^\rho)(\partial_\rho A^\nu)$ and no other terms have $(\partial_\mu\partial^\mu A^\rho)$. Is this second equation true, or is there some earlier mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $F^{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetric, so
$$\partial_\mu (F^{\rho\mu}\partial_\rho A^\nu) =  \partial_\mu F^{\rho\mu}\partial_\rho A^\nu + F^{\rho\mu}\partial_\mu \partial_\rho A^\nu = \partial_\mu F^{\rho\mu}\partial_\rho A^\nu = 0\,.$$
The last equality comes from applying the equations of motion for $\mathscr{L} = -\frac14 F^2$.

Comment: Ah, the equations of motion imply that $\partial_\mu F^{\rho\mu}=0$, and the antisymmetry means the second term $F^{\rho\mu}\partial_\mu\partial_\rho A^\nu=0$. Thanks!